# Bundler gem installed from github get installed in a different location

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install a gem from github like this:

```
gem 'omniauth', :git => "git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git", :require => "omniauth"
```

The problem is that the gem is not actually being loaded. The ruby objects are not there.

So, `bundle show omniauth` shows me: `Users/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bundler/gems/omniauth-5972c94792cf`

The problem is that the gem is being installed to a different location from the regular ones. I expected it to be `/Users/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/``

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Also, require "omniauth" fails:
LoadError: no such file to load -- omniauth

Comment: what is the actual error that you get? i used the :git option a lot and it worked all the time.

Comment: Actually the only fail I get is in the require, as in my previous comment. bundle install works fine and is grabbing the source from github, but ruby is not finding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing these two lines:

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
```

as you can see in Bundler's source code, "bundler/setup" is going to put gems managed by Bundler in the Ruby's load path:
https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/lib/bundler/setup.rb#L22

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

try changing the bundler line to.

```
gem 'omniauth', :git => "git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git", :require => 'oa-oauth'
```

The problem is that your :require property was pointing to the wrong file to load. It is not always the same name as the library, by the way, when both lib name and require are the same you don't need to specify it, only when they differs.